# Creating new columns and checking string values, but got a TypeError

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would need to create two new columns with boolean or Yes/No values to test if a link include a certain word or not. From my csv file, a sample of dataset can look as follows:

```
                Col1                    
0                        Dom.ie    
1                       Bho.int       
2              Manchester.co.uk      
...                         ...      


[1800 rows x 12 columns]
```

I would like to create these two new columns, `Check_1` and `Check_2`, if the values in Col1 contains or not a certain word; for example:

```
list_1= ['dom', 'ans', 'warm']
list_2= ['dom', 'dog', 'manchester']

                Col1                     Check_1      Check_2                     
0                        dom.ie        Yes             Yes
1                       bho.int        No               No
2              manchester.co.uk        No              Yes
...                         ...        ...


[1800 rows x 14 columns]
```

I have tried with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  

def part_is_in(x, values):
output = 'No'
for val in values:
    if val in x:
        return 'Yes'
        break                
return output

df['Check_1'] = df['Col1'].apply(part_is_in, values = list_1)
df['Check_2'] = df['Col1'].apply(part_is_in, values = list_2)
```

However, I got the following error:

> TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable

related to: `df['Check_1'] = df['Col1'].apply(part_is_in, values = list_1)` and to `if val in x`.
Could you please tell me what it means and how I can fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These solutions don't get to the root of the error. You didn't post all of the data but my guess is that Col1 could have some floats in it, which causes an error when you call `if val in x`. A column with Object dtype can have mixed types in it (good overview of this issue at https://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html).

A simple way to test this is to change it to `if val in str(x)` or, depending of your version of pandas, you could convert the entire column to string using `to_string`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Eric. It works changing it with `str(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach with `str.contains`:

```
s = df['Col1'].str.lower()
all_lsts = [list_1, list_2]

for i,lst in enumerate(all_lsts, start=1):
    df[f'Check_{i}'] = s.str.contains('|'.join(lst))
```

Output:

```
               Col1  Check_1  Check_2
0            Dom.ie     True     True
1           Bho.int    False    False
2  Manchester.co.uk    False     True
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers and help. In case I would like to populate separately (not using `df[f'Check_{i}']` or `df=df.join(s.add_prefix('check_'))`, how could I do that? In case the name of columns can be different (it will happen and  would like to use your codes to populate new columns, in case?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
import re
s=pd.concat([df.Col1.str.contains('|'.join(x),flags=re.IGNORECASE) for x in [list_1,list_2]],1)
Out[19]: 
    Col1   Col1
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False   True
df=df.join(s.add_prefix('check_'))
```